# initialising class with numpy.ndarray attribute

Tags: python, class, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to define a wrapper class having an attribute of type `numpy.ndarray`. That attribute must be initialised by calling `__init__()`.

The script runs as expected for 1D arrays. However, in the case of multi-dimensionnal arrays, python returns the following error : `only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

```
import numpy as np

class myArr(np.ndarray):
    def __init__(self,Arr):
        self.Arr = Arr

npArr = np.zeros((3)) # works
#npArr = np.zeros((3,5)) # does not work
print npArr

wrappedArr = myArr(npArr)
print wrappedArr.Arr
```

What is happening here ?

python 2.7.6, numpy 1.8.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to have an attribute of type `ndarray` is there any specific reason you inherit from it?

I'd say that by subclassing `ndarray` and overriding `__init__` you're messing with numpy's initialisation process, thus generating the error you're seeing.

See the numpy docs about [Subclassing ndarray](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html#implications-for-subclassing) for more info.

Inheriting from `object` (converting `MyArr` to a regular new-style class) solves your problem:

```
import numpy as np

class MyArr(object):
    def __init__(self, arr):
        self.arr = arr

np_arr_1 = np.zeros((3))
np_arr_2 = np.zeros((3, 5))

wrapped_arr_1 = MyArr(np_arr_1)
wrapped_arr_2 = MyArr(np_arr_2)

print wrapped_arr_1.arr
print wrapped_arr_2.arr
```

Comment: thanks for your answer ! The reason why I am implementing this wrapper class is that I have a code where `numpy.roll()` is very often called, usually multiple times in a single code line. In order to improve code readability, I would like to define a `__call__()` method as a replacement. It would be defined something like `__call__(i,j): numpy.roll(self,[i,j])`. Do you think that's the suitable approach ?

Comment: I don't think you need to go through the hassle of subclassing `ndarray`, just call `numpy.call` using `self.arr` instead of `self`